# Reference one task from another in a contact flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, telephony, amazon-connect

I'm building a contact flow which creates a block of tasks in pairs.  Ideally, one task in a pair should include a reference to its partner in its description.

I've *almost* achieved this: When creating the second task, I add a reference type URL and I'm using the `$.Task.ContactId` attribute, prefixed with the access URL for my instance, i.e.

`https://<myurl>.my.connect.aws/connect/contact-trace-records/details/$.Task.ContactID`

I'd like to deploy this in more than one Connect instance without having to keep manually editing the contact flow.  Is there any way I can specify the access URL as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic attributes like this, you need to call a lambda. The lambda can return the appropriate value and then you can use that returned value to set your reference URL attribute.

If I was writing the lambda I'd send through the `$.Task.ContactID` then use `Details.ContactData.InstanceARN` from the event that gets passed to the lambda to lookup the instance alias via the Connect API [`DescribeInstance`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstance.html) function. You can then build the url in the lambda and send it back.

More info about using lambdas in a contact flow can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/connect-lambda-functions.html)